# No response to ICMP (traceroute)

Tags: wireshark, traceroute

192.168.1.37 can ping 192.168.0.22, 
but can't ping 192.168.0.240

subnet masks are 255.255.255.0 on all hosts in question

Switch/gateway in the middle (192.168.1.253) can ping both of these addresses, and it also contains a correct ARP entry for 192.168.0.240

When I run tracert on 192.168.1.37, pointing to 192.168.0.**22** I get a tracert response:

> 1   1 ms   <1 ms   <1 ms   192.168.1.253
>
> 2   <1ms   <1 ms   <1 ms  192.168.0.22

But there is no tracert response when I point it to 192.168.0.**240**.
When I check the wireshark trace for ICMP responses - there are none!
Looks like the gateway is not responding to ICMP packet sent to that remote address at all.

What else can I check? Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:
Both 192.168.0.**22** and 192.168.0.**240** have the same default gateway defined.
I can ping 192.168.1.37 from 192.168.0.**22** but not from 192.168.0.**240**

**UPDATE 2**:
When I change IP address on the 'difficult' host from 192.168.0.**240** to 192.168.0.**34** everything works well! When I change it back to .240 it stops responding to pings from the other subnet. What is causing it? We are running a bit short on IP addresses, so it would be good to know why .240 doesn't work.

Comment: Check that the 240 host has the correct default gateway.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you for the comment - will add it to the answer

Comment: Can you ping the other way?  Does the host have a firewall ?

Comment: added updates to the question!

Comment: (ICMP) Filtering on the gateway router or switch?

Comment: Can it be address-specific? Because I can do tracert to another host in the other subnet successfully

Comment: Duplicate address?

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is in the "switch/gateway" - what brand are you using? What configuration?

Comment: My colleague has resolved the problem - will give an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have cleared ARP table on both hosts and the switch.
That has somehow resolved the problem, despite the fact that we have previously manually checked that the ARP table on the switch contains a correct entry:

> show ip arp | grep 0.240

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.